# Populating HTML Divs (projects) from a SQL database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

I have finaly took the breath again to work on my portfolio. I am populating an div with data out of a SQL database. It is working, but something tells me I am using PHP the wrong way, and I should not have PHP and HTML codes mixed up in eachother.

My PHP Output is like this:

```
 <div class="content">
    <h3>{ <em>Showcase</em> }</h3>
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $typeDescription = $row['type_description'];
            $typeDescription = ucfirst($typeDescription);

            echo ('<div class="project-thumb">');
            echo ('<div class="banner-container">');
            echo ('<h3>'.$typeDescription."</h3>");
            echo ('<img src="'.$imagePath.$row['short_description']."_banner.png".'"/>');
            echo ('<img class="banner-fold" src="'.$imagePath.$row['short_description']."_fold.png".'"/>');
            echo ('</div>');
            echo ('<img class= "main-image" src="'.$imagePath.$row['project_image'].'"/>');
            echo('<h5>'.$row['project_year'].'</h5>');
            echo('<h3>'.$row['project_name'].'</h3>');
            echo('<p>'.$row['project_description']."</p>");
            echo ('</div>');
        }
    ?>
```

What is a more effective way to achieve what I want, (Load Name / Image / Content) out of a database and **for each project** create an div so my projects will be sorted on my Showcase (Portfolio Page)?

I have searched around the boards, and even looked up for video's if there is a possible way to make some neater code. But all i get are Form Application Tutorials with Ajax.

I hope you guys can help me out!

Kind Regards!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not belong here. It may be recieved better on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's good to reach php documentation sometimes, Specially Intro.
http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you are mixing presentation with your business logic.  This is like

using **HTML** `<p style="color:red;">RED</p>`

instead of using **HTML/CSS** `<p>RED</p>` and `p { color:red}`

One approach to do this in PHP involves *[template engines](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/getting-started-with-php-templating/)* such as [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/intro.html#basic-api-usage), eg

```
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Array(array(
    'index' => 'Hello {{ name }}!',
));
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

echo $twig->render('index', array('name' => 'Fabien'));
```

Comment: I have been looking for more information about the Twig Templates today. It is definitily something that I can use, so this would mean my question is anwsered and I can continue on my Portfolio.

Now I am using raw data strings in an Array, my question is if i can fill this data later with SQL queries?

Thanks!